# Reading file into lists

Tags: haskell

I have just recently started learning Haskell,and what I am trying to do is this:

I have a txt file like this

```
2000
booka 500

bookb 1000

bookc 250

bookd 250
```

and I want my output  like this

```
booka 25%
bookb 50%
bookc 12.5%
bookd 12.5%
```

I can read the conten from the file with readFile but I dont know how to treat the content after

this is what I have

```
-- Imports needed
import System.IO
import Data.List

main = do
    putStrLn "Please insert the name of the file you want to process:"
    file <- getLine
    read_File file  

read_File file = do
h <- openFile file ReadMode
content <- readFile file
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be opening the file with `openFile`, then reading the file with `readFile`.  You only need the latter, it is a handy function that opens the file, reads it, returns the contents, then closes the file safely for you.

What you should be aiming to write is a pure function

```
processContents :: String -> Maybe (Float, [(String, Float)])
```

that can get the first number from the file and then each successive line.  Since we want to ensure our code is robust, we should also handle failures in some way.  For this problem, I think using `Maybe` is sufficient to handle errors in parsing.  For this, we'll add a couple imports:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.Maybe

processContents :: String -> Maybe (Float, [(String, Float)])
processContents c = do
    let ls = lines c
    -- If we can't get a single line, the whole operation fails
    firstLine <- listToMaybe ls
    -- If we can't parse the total, the whole operation fails
    total <- readMaybe firstLine
    let rest = drop 1 ls
    return (total, catMaybes $ map parseLine $ rest)
```

The `listToMaybe` function acts as a "safe head", it is defined as

```
listToMaybe (x:xs) = Just x
listToMaybe [] = Nothing
```

The `readMaybe` function has the type `Read a => String -> Maybe a`, and returns `Nothing` if it couldn't parse the value, making it easy to use in this case.  The `catMaybes` function takes a list of `Maybe a`s, extracts all the ones that aren't `Nothing`, and returns the rest as a list with the type `catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`.

Now we just need to implement `parseLine`:

```
parseLine :: String -> Maybe (String, Float)
parseLine line = case words line of
    (book:costStr:_) -> do
        cost <- readMaybe costStr
        return (book, cost)
    _ -> Nothing
```

This breaks the line up by spaces, grabs the first two elements, and parses them into a name and a number, if possible.

Now you have a function that could parse your example file into the value

```
Just (2000.0, [("booka", 500.0), ("bookb", 1000.0), ("bookc", 250.0), ("bookd", 250.0)])
```

Now it's just up to you to figure out how calculate the percentages and print it to the screen in your desired format.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to break down the problem into three obvious parts:

1. Parse the input.
2. Process the input to obtain the results.
3. Print the results.

Indeed, almost all data-processing problems can be broken down like this.

#### Parsing the input

Parsing the input materialises into reading the file and then breaking the contents up into a list of lines. The first of these lines contains a total value, the remaining lines form a table of rows consisting of a label and a value:

```
parseFile :: FilePath -> IO (Float, [(String, Float)])
parseFile fp = do
  contents <- readFile fp
  let (s : ss) = lines contents
  return (read s, parseTable ss)
```

The table is parsed by means of an auxiliary function that breaks each line up into a list of two words: one for the label, one for the value.

```
parseTable :: [String] ->   [(String, Float)]
parseTable []        = []
parseTable ("" : ss) = parseTable ss
parseTable (s : ss)  = let [s1, s2] = words s
                       in (s1, read s2) : parseTable ss
```

#### Processing the input

Processing the input is straightforward:

```
processTable :: Float -> [(String, Float)] -> [(String, Float)]
processTable sum table = [(label, (part / sum) * 100) | (label, part) <- table]
```

The second component of each row in the table is divided by the total value and then multiplied by hundred to yield a percentage.

#### Printing the results

A textual rendering of single row consisting, now, of a label and a percentage is easily obtained:

```
showRow :: (String, Float) -> String
showRow (label, perc) = label ++ " " ++ show perc ++ "%"
```

Putting it all together, a whole file is then processed by (1) parsing it to obtain a total value and a table, (2) processing the table to obtain a processed table, and (3) printing the processed table row by row:

```
processFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
processFile fp = do
  (sum, table) <- parseFile fp
  mapM_ (putStrLn . showRow) (processTable sum table)
```

For your example data, this generates *almost* the output as you specified it:

```
booka 25.0%
bookb 50.0%
bookc 12.5%
bookd 12.5%
```

That is, getting rid of trailing `".0"`s in printed floating-point numbers is left as an exercise. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To "store" the lines of the file you can just call:

```
fileContent <- readFile file
let fileLines = lines fileContent
```

from there you can use `words` for every line and it will return a list of [label, amount]. You can read the `amount` with `read` to place it back into some integral or fractional form.

[<kbd>Live solution</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c7fa522761e09f6)